# Typo3 Introduction Package Installation not working

Tags: typo3

Edit: Sry for spam.. I can browse from backend -> Web -> View

I'm new to Typo3. I installed 7.3 on apache on ubuntu 14.04. When I install the Introduction Package from the backend Admin Tools -> Extensions -> get preconfigured distribution, I can 'View Webpage' and see the fault site, but all the feature descriptions dont work. They refer to /typo3/typo3_src-7.3.0/features/ when they should refer to id=35 (in LTS I could access these trhough URL's.)

I'd love to browse these locally without manually entering URL's instead of the official page.

Any help is apreciated, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the Apache module `mod_rewrite` and make sure that the file `.htaccess` exists in your root directory. Or you can disable the TYPO3 extension `realurl`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. links didnt work in the beginning .. 'module rewrite already enabled' disabling the extension realul not working even after uncommenting rewritebase in _.htaccess. (due to dependency introduction package). I re-enabled and disabled the introduction package & realurl , now both are deactivated, and links work. (linking to id=x). Thanks for the help